# Call search function when user is done Typing

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have the following problem,

I have this piece of code in my Javascript file,

```
    termChange(evt) {
        this.rows = [];
        this.searchTerm = evt.target.value;
        this.getCases();
    }
```

This clears out the rows returned after the search takes place, gets the search term through the event taking place and then calls getCases.

This Code block calls another async function, getCases, that gets a response from our server and gets the results back. The html has onChange = {termChange}. However this is where the problem comes in. Every-time you type, it calls it, causing it to fire 8 times while searching. This results in unwanted search results, and duplicates at times. I need to figure out a way to call this event after the user has finished typing. I have tried to setTimeouts, and even use a debounce. However neither I could get to work in order to solve the problem. Any help with this would be huge. Thanks!

It has to automatically search when the user finishes typing without any movements or button presses.

```
    debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
        var timeout;
        return function executedFunction() {
          var context = this;
          var args = arguments;
          var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
            };
          var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
          clearTimeout(timeout);
          timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
          if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
        };
    }
```

This is the debounce function I wrote. However when I tried to do something along the lines of

```
    handleTermChange = this.debounce(this.termChange(), 1000, false);
```

It throws me an error that it can not find target of undefined. So it does not pass the event through and I could not figure out away to do this and make it work, hence my problem with debounce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debounce is 100% the way to go - it describes exactly what you're trying to do.  Maybe you need a longer timer?  Or there was something wrong with the debounce function?

I use a 250ms timer on the site I maintain's search box - but if it's a slower API or if it makes major page rewrites, you'd probably want to go larger.

Also check to make sure the input actually changed... e.g. store the last searched term and abort it in the search function if new input = old input

Comment: I believe you are right, I edited my question to include the problem I ran into with the debounce function. Please let me know if you know how to get around it.

Comment: Hi, Set timeout function on keyup event as below.
<script>
var timeout = null;
function onKeyUpFunction() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
          //Your search code
    }, 500);

}
</script>

Comment: I believe I tried that Dhananjay Chaudhari, I will try it again the way you have it but I was running into a different problem when doing this I believe. I will let you know.

Comment: onKeyUpFunction(evt){
        var timeout = null;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            this.rows = [];
            this.searchTerm = evt.target.value;
            this.getCases();
        }, 1000)
    }       This is how it looks when I try what Dhananjay said to do with Salesforce. However when i run this it then throws me an error saying this.getCases() is not a function. Even though it is.

Comment: Might need to bind it?  If you put .bind(this) after the method, it'll explicitly define "this" inside the function

Comment: I had to either bind it or put this as the context in the debounce function. I finally figured it out. Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try using on blur event instead of calling event each time the user types.

Comment: I have done this, it does make it work. However, then it is not automatically searching when you are done typing and requires a mouse movement so it doesn't fully solve the problem.

Comment: If its a static input with a specific number of characters like you said it fired 8 times while searching, use a mask and a if statement within the keyup event to equal the length of the input with the length of the mask.

Comment: They are searching through a vehicle list, they either use an 8 digit case number, or a VIN. So it can be either or, do you think it would still work if I made it fire after both lengths? (I will try it anyways). This will probably work too, however I still am not sure if it is what they are looking for. What if they wanted to search by half the vin just to filter some results out, I can see issues if I deem it by length.

Comment: It does not work sadly :(. Well it does but it is not what I need.

Comment: if you are looking for this kind of behavior and call function when user stops typing instead of clicking on a button then you should use timeout or debounce.

Comment: Yeah that is what I said in the original problem, I figured that but I can not seem to get them to work properly with my code. I even edited it to include the debounce I was using.

Answer (score 0):

Use onkeyup event.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="termChange(event)">
```

**JS:**

```
var timeout = null;
function termChange(evt) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
          //Your code
    }, 500);

}
```

Comment: This does make the search work properly, however it is not an automatic search function if I change it to onblur which is why I can not use this. It has to search automatically as you are done typing without having to move the mouse or do anything else.